# EL Property Not found exception, getter method correct

Tags: servlets, jstl

I am trying to diplay a field using EL but I keep getting an exception even though the getter method is correct. What else could it be here is the table I am displaying,:

```
                 <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${sessionScope.user.email}"></c:out></td>
                    <td id="myusername"><c:out value="${sessionScope.user.userName}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${sessionScope.user.userID}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${sessionScope.user.cardListSize}"></c:out></td>
                    <td id="currentrank"><c:out value="${sessionScope.user.rank}"></c:out></td>
                    <td hidden="true" id="currentpoints"><c:out value="${sessionScope.user.points}"></c:out></td>
                </tr>
```

`${sessionScope.user.rank}` and `${sessionScope.user.points}` are what is causing the error, if I remove those two everything else loads correctly. Here is how I set the attribute before forwarding to this JSP:

```
       UserAccount userAccount = DataDAO.findUser(userName, password);
       HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
       session.setAttribute("user",userAccount);
```

here is part of the UserAccount object:

```
    public String getRank(){
      return rank;
    }

    public Integer getPoints(){
      return points;
     }
```

this is where I create that object after retrieving info from the DB:

```
        if(password.equals(rightPassword)){
                 Integer userspoints = user.getInt("points");
                 String rank = DataAnalyzer.determineRank(userspoints);
                 UserAccount retrievedUser = new UserAccount(userName,rightPassword,user.getString("firstname"),user.getString("lastname"),user.getString("email"),rank,userspoints,user.getString("avatar"));

                 Integer userID = user.getInt("USER_ID");
                 retrievedUser.setUserID(userID.toString());

                 return retrievedUser;
             } else {
                 return null;
             }
```

If one of those fields was null would that cause a property not found exception ?

stacktrace:

> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/QuestionPage.jsp at line 90

87:                         
88:                         
89:                         
90:             ${sessionScope.user.rank}
91:                         ${sessionScope.user.points}
92:                     
93:

Stacktrace:

> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:578)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:401)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     flashcardshark.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'rank' not found on type
>   flashcardshark.bean.UserAccount
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
>     javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
>     org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.QuestionPage_jsp._jspService(QuestionPage_jsp.java:229)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:401)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     flashcardshark.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: You can put not null condition before diplaying field.

Comment: You're not running the code you think you're running. Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart, etc.

Comment: Doesn't tomcat recompile automatically after you make a change ?